# how to use DWM and patch it in Ubuntu 20.04 gnome?

Tags: 20.04, window-manager, tiling

I have a clean installation of pop os 20.04 and want to try out suckless software, specially dwm. I have done `sudo apt install dwm suckless-tools stterm surf` and it worked. I now have the option at the login screen to change gnome for dwm. I can use dmenu and stterm.

But how can I patch it since it wasn't downloaded from git, I have done `apt-get build-dep dwm` to get all the needed tools to compile it and also `apt-get source dwm` to get the source code into my home folder but it is not a git repository.

I've tried the simplest thing, to change the Alt key for the Super key without any success. I have copied the config.def.h into a config.h, that files is the one I am modifying then I run `sudo make clean install` and it does not throw any errors but it does not change the Mod1 for Mod4 keys even after reboot.

Besides that, I am very interested in patching the dwm with the center layout as well as adding slstatus to the status bar since this is a laptop. I haven't found any post about this, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use it by cloning it into a repository and installing it by using `make clean install`. Even this guide which is linked from the official dwm website asks you to first download the source and then install it.

I would say first uninstall dwm using

```
sudo apt uninstall dwm
```

Then follow either one of the following guides.

[Installing and configuring dwm under ubuntu](https://cannibalcandy.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/installing-and-configuring-dwm-under-ubuntu/)

This is a complete guide on using DWM [Dwm: The Suckless Window Manager](https://dev.to/l04db4l4nc3r/dwm-the-suckless-window-manager-1ji)